# dojox.grid.DataGrid making multi row header

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I want to make grid with multi row header using dojox.grid.Datagrid:

```
    <table  data-dojo-id="monthReportTable" data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.DataGrid" autoHeight="true" autoWidth="true">
    <thead>
    <tr>
       <th field="employee"   rowspan="2"    width="150px"     >Сотрудник</th>
       <th field="division"   rowspan="2"    width="150px"     >Подразделение</th>
       <th field="region"     rowspan="2"    width="100px"     >Регион</th>
       <th field="ts_month"   colspan="3"                     >В табель за месяц</th>
       <th field="calc_month" colspan="3"                     >Расчетные показатели за месяц</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th field="ts_worked"              width="100px" title="Количество отработанных дней (фактическое)"      >Отработано</th>
        <th field="ts_vacation"            width="100px" title="Количество дней отпуска"                         >Отпуск</th>
        <th field="ts_illness"             width="100px" title="Количество дней болезни"                         >Больничный</th>

        <th field="calc_worked_plan"       width="100px" title="Количество отработанных дней (плановое)"         >Отработано (план)</th>
        <th field="calc_worked_fact"       width="100px" title="Количество отработанных дней (фактическое)"      >Отработано (факт)</th>
        <th field="calc_vacation"          width="100px" title="Количество дней отпуска"                         >Отпуск</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

I hope to get something like this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/iepnjk1aan9el72/1.PNG?dl=0

But then I initialize the store, I had this picture:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cnt4lzhsjex2jj5/2.PNG?dl=0

A row has big height, and without another columns. Don't understand why so, because there is no error in browser console. It does not work properly in FF and Chrome.

So, I think may there must be some specific kind of store? Anybody has problem like this? How to solve problem?

Comment: At the end I attach store structure: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vijjscsl6fq7l99/3.PNG?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

check this link https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/datagrid/demo/datagrid-subrows.html look at the source code.